# Is querySelectorAll a good way to select elements in multiple charts?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to highlight elements from the same dimension (Country in this example) in multiple charts. Assigning a class to each country at the point of generation of `rect` or `circle` and then using `querySeletorAll` to find all matching elements seems to work, but I wonder if there is a better way. This feels a little hack-y.

Please see this [block](https://bl.ocks.org/gherka/bc9ec7b0178a744fe75ebd7b50153312) for a working demo.

Both the bar chart and the scatter have classes assigned to their elements (`rect` and `circle`) in the same way:

```
var enter = svgContainer.selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('rect')
  .attr('class', function(d) { return "mycharts_bars_" + d.Country; })
```

And then the highlight on hover does this:

```
  .on("mouseover", function(d) { 

  var hover_value = this.__data__.Country; 
  var hover_elems = document.querySelectorAll(`[class*="${hover_value}"]`);

  for (let item of hover_elems) {
    item.setAttribute('fill', 'hotpink');}
    })
```

Comment: The code review stack exchange is a better place to ask this. Since your code is at least working. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I also used to recommend CodeReview for questions like this, but I received a lot of complaints from CR users, which discourage such migrations. So, today, I recommend CodeReview only for very specific questions.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I didn't think of posting it on Code Review because it was a general design pattern problem (highlighting on separate charts) and the code was for illustration only which [this meta guide](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) discourages.

Comment: @gherka Yes, you're correct, your question ticks the boxes 2, 3 and maybe 4, but not all of them... it's a borderline question for CR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/9ffa69f363b5ee9af2171879d798091eab68def0/src/selectAll.js#L3), `d3.selectAll` already uses `document.querySelectorAll` internally:

```
export default function(selector) {
  return typeof selector === "string"
      ? new Selection([document.querySelectorAll(selector)], [document.documentElement])
      : new Selection([selector == null ? [] : selector], root);
}
```

So, you can safely use `selectAll`, which makes your code more idiomatic for D3 programmers.

However, there are some issues in your code:

First, you don't need that `var hover_value = this.__data__.Country;`. You already have the datum as the first argument! Therefore, it can be just `d.Country`.

Secondly, you don't need to deal with classes if you don't want, just select the element. You can use classes if you want, that's not a big problem, but you definitely don't need that `for...of` loop. As a rule of thumb, do not use loops in a D3 code (there are specific situations where they are needed, but not this one).

All that being said, the function can be simply this:

```
d3.selectAll("circle, rect").attr("fill", function(e) {
    return e.Country === d.Country ? "pink" : "grey"
});
```

Or, since only the rectangle hovered over will change colour:

```
d3.select(this).attr("fill", "pink");
d3.selectAll("circle").attr("fill", function(e) {
    return e.Country === d.Country ? "pink" : "grey"
});
```

As a side note, this will change **all** selected elements in the page. I'm doing this only because, in your example, you have very few elements. If in your real chart you have hundreds of elements a better solution is first filtering them and after that applying the changes (both on `mouseover` and `mouseout`), which gives you better performance.

Here is your code with that change: https://blockbuilder.org/GerardoFurtado/e54f2f0cc711b51be4b400627cac6f51